# Windows Server Service Bus | Deployment

Tags: servicebus

So far I'm aware that the supported [topologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193006%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) range from single node installation to 3 node installation of Windows Server Service Bus.

What would be the expected behaviour if a farm of only two nodes is created? Is it better to use just one node rather than two nodes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in a [Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/27735b0d-6d38-44b4-8fc0-933861874625/service-bus-farm-wcf-client-configuration?forum=servbus#d8fb6fda-c0ed-4a18-9a0a-f0db4da0ae51) the only supported topologies are single node or three nodes.

On a two node scenario if one of the nodes fail, the whole system will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge performance of most messaging scenarios is bound by SQL server I/O and to optimize the SQL Server hard disks for write performance. If the server is equipped with sufficient memory, SQL Server rarely reads data from disk. If the server is equipped with more than two disks, stripe the disks that contain the log and data stores.

Considering above points when tuning the SQL Server that hosts the Service Bus for Windows Server container databases  it always perform better for 3 nodes installation rather than two.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It says little about the Service Bus itself.